# block allocation in unixFreeBSD

Tags: unix

From **FreeBSD UNIX** (Galvin),

> Suppose data are written to a file in transfer sizes of 1-KB bytes, and the
>   block and fragment sizes of the file system are 4 KB and 512 bytes. The file
>   system will allocate a 1-KB fragment to contain the data from the first transfer.
>   The next transfer will cause a new 2-KB fragment to be allocated. The data
>   from the original fragment must be copied into this new fragment, followed
>   by the second 1-KB transfer. The allocation routines do attempt to find the
>   required space on the disk immediately following the existing fragment so
>   that no copying is necessary, but if they cannot do so, up to seven copies may
>   be required before the fragment becomes a block. Provisions have been made
>   for programs to discover the block size for a file so that transfers of that size
>   can be made, to avoid fragment recopying.

Can you please explain what the author is trying to say here?  Why shouldn't a 4 kB block be allocated to write and then a 512 bytes fragment?  Author is talking about general filesystem in UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

The FreeBSD file system is apparently doing some moderately clever special processing for to prevent the "small files take up too much space because each one uses a disk block" problem that used to plague unix boxes after disks got big, but files systems still lived in the '80s.

*This is good.*

But if you write a medium to large file in small pieces, you can fool the file system into using the "small file" hack in a wasteful way.

*This is bad. And slow. And tough on solid state "disk" devices.*

If you write your medium to large files in chucks at least as big as a disk block, the "small file" hack  isn't invoked. And none of those problems occur.

*This is better.*